# Django and stripe handle successful payment

Tags: django, stripe-payments, webhooks

I am trying to  handle successful payment using stripe webhook, in my stripe dashboard I see that the events  are triggered  and the payment_intent is successful but the order is not created

views.py :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.http import HttpResponse
import stripe
import json
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt, csrf_protect
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST
from article.models import Order






endpoint_secret = '1wwww'
@require_POST
@csrf_exempt
def my_webhook_view(request):

    payload = request.body
    sig_header = request.META['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE']
    event = None

    # Try to validate and create a local instance of the event
    try:
        event = stripe.Webhook.construct_event(payload, sig_header, endpoint_secret)
    except ValueError as e:
        # Invalid payload
        return HttpResponse(status=400)
    except stripe.error.SignatureVerificationError as e:
        # Invalid signature
        return HttpResponse(status=400)

  # Handle the checkout.session.completed event
    if event['type'] == 'payment_intent.succeeded':
        checkout_session = event['data']['object']
        # Make sure is already paid and not delayed
       
        _handle_successful_payment(checkout_session)

    # Passed signature verification
    return HttpResponse(status=200)

def _handle_successful_payment(checkout_session):

    payed_order = Order.objects.create(order_id='test22')
    return payed_order
```

Comment: I think the first question here would be whether the webhook events are successfully delivered to your server. Subsequently, I would suggest adding logs to your server side code and walking through them to figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: i am getting a bad request on my terminal  and I copied and pasted the code from  a tutorial (for him it works fine)  :Bad Request: /subscription/stripe_webhook/
[17/Jan/2022 13:40:13] "POST /subscription/stripe_webhook/ HTTP/1.1" 400 0

Comment: Since you mentioned your server is returning 400 HTTP Response, which exception is it? i.e. invalid payload or invalid signature?

Comment: @alex   invalid signature   when I used the  stripe CLI  it gave me the wrong  webhook secret, not wrong  there was one more character

Comment: it sounds like you've managed to resolve the issue? or are you still having trouble?

Comment: @alex  no it's fixed now thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

According to Stripe, they recommend listening to events instead of the webhook to ensure tracking the payment status.

"Stripe recommends handling the payment_intent.succeeded, payment_intent.processing, and payment_intent.payment_failed events.

Listen for these events rather than waiting on a callback from the client. On the client, the customer could close the browser window or quit the app before the callback executes. Setting up your integration to listen for asynchronous events is what enables you to accept different types of payment methods with a single integration."
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/quickstart

I have modified the checkout.js that provided by stripe a little bit. My case, I disabled the return_url and I wait for a successful payment and submit a hidden form to place the order.

This is my workaround. If someone has something better, it would appreciated.

```
// This is your test publishable API key.
const stripe = Stripe("YOUR_KEY");
let theSecret;
let elements;

function getCookie(name) {
  let cookieValue = null;
  if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
    const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
      const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
      // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
      if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return cookieValue;
}
const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

initialize();
// checkStatus();

document
  .querySelector("#payment-form")
  .addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit);

// Fetches a payment intent and captures the client secret
async function initialize() {
  const response = await fetch("/api/create-payment-intent", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      // These values are passed at the template.
      amount: order_amount,
      currency: order_currency
    }),
  });
  const {
    clientSecret
  } = await response.json();
  theSecret = clientSecret
  const appearance = {
    theme: 'stripe',
  };
  elements = stripe.elements({
    appearance,
    clientSecret
  });
  const paymentElement = elements.create("payment");
  paymentElement.mount("#payment-element");
}

async function handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  setLoading(true);
  const {
    error
  } = await stripe.confirmPayment({
    elements,
    confirmParams: {
      // I stopped the redirect.
      // Make sure to change this to your payment completion page
      return_url: "",
    },
    redirect: "if_required"
  });
  // Here I check the status of the event instead of the redirect.
  checkStatus();
  setLoading(false);
}

// Fetches the payment intent status after payment submission
async function checkStatus() {
  const {
    paymentIntent
  } = await stripe.retrievePaymentIntent(theSecret);

  switch (paymentIntent.status) {
    case "succeeded":
      document.getElementById("place_order_form").submit();
      showMessage("Payment succeeded!");
      break;
    case "processing":
      showMessage("Your payment is processing.");
      break;
    case "requires_payment_method":
      showMessage("Your payment was not successful, please try again.");
      break;
    default:
      showMessage("Something went wrong.");
      break;
  }
}

// ------- UI helpers -------

function showMessage(messageText) {
  const messageContainer = document.querySelector("#payment-message");

  messageContainer.classList.remove("hidden");
  messageContainer.textContent = messageText;

  setTimeout(function () {
    messageContainer.classList.add("hidden");
    messageText.textContent = "";
  }, 4000);
}

// Show a spinner on payment submission
function setLoading(isLoading) {
  if (isLoading) {
    // Disable the button and show a spinner
    document.querySelector("#submit").disabled = true;
    document.querySelector("#spinner").classList.remove("hidden");
    document.querySelector("#button-text").classList.add("hidden");
  } else {
    document.querySelector("#submit").disabled = false;
    document.querySelector("#spinner").classList.add("hidden");
    document.querySelector("#button-text").classList.remove("hidden");
  }
}
```